# Python gets json list from curl incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

Im using python3, i send a POST curl request to my API:

```
curl --header "Content-Type application/json" --request POST --data '{"tags": "['a1','b2']"}'
```

My API code gets it as a dict, but like this :

```
data = request.get_data()
data = json.loads(data)
print(data["tags"])
```

log >>  [a1,b2]

i need it to be :

```
"['a1','b2']"
```

because im sending it to ansible-playbook which needs to get 
--extra-vars tags="['a1','b2']"

I tried some manipulation in my code but as the code gets data["tags"] as str instead of a list i cant.

what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to let the console print out the quotation marks too?

If yes, your json data should be `{"tags": "\"[\'a1\', \'b2\']\""}`

Comment: `{"tags"}: "\"[\'a1\', \'b2\']\""` this is not a json format, how can i apply it?

Comment: the string is `"\"[\'a1\', \'b2\']\""`

Comment: and oops I misput the `}`. It should be at the last.

Comment: thanks, i ended up sending it like this :
`curl --header "Content-Type application/json" --request POST --data {"tags": "[\'a1\', \'b2\']"`

Answer (score 0):

If `data['tags']` is a string, I can think of several possible solutions:

- User regular expressions to add `'` around each tag in a given a
  string
- Iterate over string, replacing `[` to `['`, `,` to `','` and
  `]` to `']`. Of course, this one depends on the absence of spaces
  between tags.
- If possible tags values are known - just look for them
  in a given string

My preference would be to use a regular expression, but it is not possible to write one without knowing what possible tag may look like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on the Python side, and not even on the curl side; instead it's a matter of how the shell interprets the command line before it passes the arguments to curl. You can see what happens if you use `echo` instead of `curl`:

```
echo '{"tags": "['a1','b2']"}'
```

outputs:

```
{"tags": "[a1,b2]"}
```

You can't simply use single quotes inside a string delimited by those same single quotes. My first thought was to escape the single quotes to solve the problem, but I can't find a way to do that. Therefore I think it's better to use double quotes as string delimiters, and escape the double quotes within the string (with a backslash), like so:

```
echo "{\"tags\": \"['a1','b2']\"}"
```

outputs:

```
{"tags": "['a1','b2']"}
```

So changing the curl command to this should work:

```
curl --header "Content-Type application/json" --request POST --data "{\"tags\": \"['a1','b2']\"}"
```

Quite cumbersome if you ask me, but I don't immediately see a better way.